# Not able to run the program from CMD terminal

Tags: python, anaconda, oserror

I have two anaconda navigator installed in my PC in different directories. Until recently the program was running really good but now I am getting the following error.

```
E:\Depression Detection\Depression Detection\main>activate depression

(depression) E:\Depression Detection\Depression Detection\main>python interact.py
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.8.13)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "interact.py", line 13, in <module>
    import vlc
  File "F:\anaconda\envs\depression\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 220, in <module>
    dll, plugin_path  = find_lib()
  File "F:\anaconda\envs\depression\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 183, in find_lib
    dll = ctypes.CDLL(p)
  File "F:\anaconda\envs\depression\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```